# Writing a code in javascript with radio buttons and using if else loop to calculate simple and/or compound interest

Tags: javascript, html

I have been asked to write a code in javascript to show the results in the output boxes based on the input data, the form should like the one shown in the attached image:Interest Calculator

[image: Interest Calculator]

Till now, I have written down the following code; however I am unable to get the results in the output boxes. Could someone please help. Thanks in advance.

```js
function calc() {
  {
    var p = document.getElementById("p").value;
    var r = document.getElementById("r").value;
    var t = document.getElementById("t").value;
    var int = f.int.value;
  }
  if (int === "si") {
    var sip = (p * r * t) / 100
    var ta = p + sip
    document.getElementById("i").innerHTML = sip;
    document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = ta;
  } else {
    var cta = p * (Math.pow((1 + r / 100), t))
    var cmp = cta - p
    document.getElementById("i").innerHTML = cmp;
    document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = cta;
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="f">
  <h1> Interest Calculator </h1>
  Principal = <input type="text" id="p" autofocus>
  <br><br><br> Rate of Interest = <input type="text" id="r">
  <br><br><br> Time (in years) = <input type="text" id="t">
  <br><br>
  <h1> Interest Type </h1>
  <input type="radio" name="int" id="int" value="si"> Simple Interest &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
  <input type="radio" name="int" id="int" value="ci"> Compound Interest
  <br><br>
  <hr noshade> Interest <input type="text" id="i">
  <br><br> Amount <input type="text" id="a">
  <br><br>
  <input type="button" name="cal" value="Calculate" onclick="calc()"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`innerHTML` is used to retrieve or update the content/markup inside a DOM node that can have children. For `input` elements, you have to use `value` to get or set the value of the field.

```js
function calc() {
  {
    var p = document.getElementById("p").value;
    var r = document.getElementById("r").value;
    var t = document.getElementById("t").value;
    var int = f.int.value;
  }
  
  if (int === "si") {
    console.log("simple interest");
    var sip = (p * r * t) / 100
    var ta = p + sip
    document.getElementById("i").value = sip;
    document.getElementById("a").value = ta;
  } else {
    console.log("compound interest");
    var cta = p * (Math.pow((1 + r / 100), t))
    var cmp = cta - p
    document.getElementById("i").value = cmp;
    document.getElementById("a").value = cta;
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="f">
  <h1> Interest Calculator </h1>
  Principal = <input type="text" id="p" autofocus>
  <br><br><br> Rate of Interest = <input type="text" id="r">
  <br><br><br> Time (in years) = <input type="text" id="t">
  <br><br>
  <h1> Interest Type </h1>
  <input type="radio" name="int" id="int" value="si"> Simple Interest &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
  <input type="radio" name="int" id="int" value="ci"> Compound Interest
  <br><br>
  <hr noshade> Interest <input type="text" id="i">
  <br><br> Amount <input type="text" id="a">
  <br><br>
  <input type="button" name="cal" value="Calculate" onclick="calc()"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type="reset" value="Reset"><br><br><br>
</form>
```

Comment: it worked and the results are appearing now. However, it seems only the "else" portion of the logic is activated regardless of the radio button selected. Any solution to it? Thanks once again.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. I added two `console.log()` for debugging and as you can see, the output is as expected depending on the radio button you selected. Of course you have to select either of them or it will fall back to the else condition.

Comment: many thanks. I resolved it now. I used the checked property of the radio button in the if/else condition. I also used unique identification for "name" and "id" of the radio buttons. That resolved, many thanks for your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Replace innerHTML with value. Because input values are updated using `value` attribute. Also 
the braces here

```
{
    var p = document.getElementById("p").value;
    var r = document.getElementById("r").value;
    var t = document.getElementById("t").value;
    var int = f.int.value;
  }
```

is not required.

```js
function calc() {
  var p = document.getElementById("p").value;
  var r = document.getElementById("r").value;
  var t = document.getElementById("t").value;
  var int = f.int.value;

  if (int === "si") {
    var sip = (p * r * t) / 100
    var ta = p + sip
    document.getElementById("i").value = sip;
    document.getElementById("a").value = ta;
  } else {
    var cta = p * (Math.pow((1 + r / 100), t))
    var cmp = cta - p
    document.getElementById("i").value = cmp;
    document.getElementById("a").value = cta;
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="f">
  <h1> Interest Calculator </h1>
  Principal = <input type="text" id="p" autofocus>
  <br><br><br> Rate of Interest = <input type="text" id="r">
  <br><br><br> Time (in years) = <input type="text" id="t">
  <br><br>
  <h1> Interest Type </h1>
  <input type="radio" name="int" id="int" value="si"> Simple Interest &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
  <input type="radio" name="int" id="int" value="ci"> Compound Interest
  <br><br>
  <hr noshade> Interest <input type="text" id="i">
  <br><br> Amount <input type="text" id="a">
  <br><br>
  <input type="button" name="cal" value="Calculate" onclick="calc()"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
```

Comment: thanks; the results are now appearing. However, another bug surfaced, whichever radio button i use, the results appear the same, the calculation is only done for compound interest (means only the else logic portion is getting activated). Any solution would be much appreciated.